# Fatal error: Trying to get string form class Mainclass

Tags: php

Что значит эта ошибка?

> `Fatal error: Trying to get string form class Mainclass in /data/home/htdocs/system/class/mainclass.php on line 46`

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в инете ничего найти не могу(
Это класс который использует Mainclass.php

```
<?php
class Order extends BaseClass
{

    public 
        $order_id,
        $order=array(),
        $items=array(),
        $itemFromPage = 99999,
        $page = 1,
        $allResult = 0,
        $debug = false,
        $child = array(),
        $childItems = array(),
        $childItemsCount = 0,
        $dStatus = 0;
    private $session = false, $updateItemId=array(), $ot = "orders", $it = "items";
    public function __construct($order_id='',$orderType = "order")
    {

        $this->setType($orderType);
        $this->getOrderId($order_id);
        if(!empty($_SESSION['current_order']['items']) and empty($_SESSION['current_order']['order_id']))
        {
            $this->sessionItemToBase();
            unset($_SESSION['current_order']);
        }
        $this->getOrder();

    }

    private function getOrderId($order_id)
    {
        if(!empty($order_id))
        {
            $this->order_id = $order_id;
        }
        elseif(empty($order_id) and !empty($_SESSION['user']['login']))
        {

            $result_db = $this->Mainclass->Db->get_('SELECT `order_id` FROM `'.$this->ot.'` WHERE `user_login` = "' . Func::code($_SESSION['user']['login']) . '" ORDER BY order_date DESC');
            echo mysql_error();
            if(!empty($result_db))
            {
                if(!empty($result_db) and !empty($result_db['order_id']))
                {
                    $this->order_id = $result_db['order_id'];
                }
                else
                    $this->getNewOrder();

            }   
        }
        elseif(empty($order_id) and empty($_SESSION['user']['login']))
        {

            $this->session = true;
        }
    }

    public function reCount()
    {
        $this->order['summ_0'] = 0;
        $this->order['items_count'] = 0;
        if(!empty($this->order) and !empty($this->items))
        {
            foreach($this->items as $d)
            {
                if($d['is_warehouse']!=3 and $d['back']!=1)
                {
                    $this->order['summ_0']+=$d['price'] * $d['count'] + $d['post_price'];
                    $this->order['items_count']+=$d['count'];
                }
            }
        }

        return array('sum'=>$this->order['summ_0'],'count'=>$this->order['items_count']);
    }

    public function setItemCat($item)
    {

        if($this->session==false)
        {

            $userId = $_SESSION['user']['id'];
            $data = $this->Mainclass->Db->get_('SELECT * FROM `cart_items` WHERE `user_id`='.$userId.' AND `num_iid`='.Func::code($item['num_iid']).' AND `sku_id`='.Func::code($item['sku_id']),1);

            if(count($data)>0)
                $query = $this->Mainclass->Db->update_('UPDATE `cart_items` SET `count`=`count`+'.((int)$item['count']).',`value`=0 WHERE `user_id`='.$userId.' AND `num_iid`='.Func::code($item['num_iid']).' AND `sku_id`='.Func::code($item['sku_id']));

            else
                $query = $this->Mainclass->Db->insert_('INSERT INTO cart_items (user_id,item_id,title,title_ch,num_iid,nick,price,sel_props_val,count,value,sku_id,user_desc,detail_url,order_id,post_price,post_type,img,params_rus,params_ch,city,state) VALUES ("'.$userId.'","' . Func::code($item['item_id']) . '","'.Func::code($item['title']).'","'.Func::code($item['title_ch']).'","' . Func::code($item['num_iid']) . '","' .Func::code($item['nick']) . '","' . Func::code($item['price']) . '","' .Func::code($item['sel_props_val']) . '","' .Func::code($item['count']) . '","' .(!empty($item['value']) ? Func::code($item['value']) : '' ). '","' .Func::code($item['sku_id']) . '","' .(!empty($item['user_desc']) ? Func::code($item['user_desc']) : '' ). '","' .Func::code($item['detail_url']) . '","' . $this->order_id . '","' .Func::code($item['post_price']) . '","' .(!empty($item['post_type']) ? Func::code($item['post_type']) : ''). '","' .Func::code($item['img']) . '","' .Func::code($item['params_rus']) . '","' .Func::code($item['params_ch']) . '","' .Func::code($item['city']) . '","' .Func::code($item['state']) . '")');

            if($query)
                $this->items[] = $item;
                return $item;
        }
        else
        {
            $_SESSION['current_order']['items'][] = $item;
            $this->items[] = $item;
        }
    }

    public function setItemTiImem($item)
    {

        if($this->session==false)
        {
            $query = $this->Mainclass->Db->insert_('INSERT INTO `items` (item_id,title,title_ch,num_iid,nick,price,sel_props_val,count,value,sku_id,user_desc,detail_url,order_id,post_price,post_type,img,params_rus,params_ch,city,state) VALUES ("' .Func::code($item['item_id']) . '","'.Func::code($item['title']).'","'.Func::code($item['title_ch']).'","' .Func::code($item['num_iid']) . '","' .Func::code($item['nick']) . '","' .Func::code($item['price']) . '","' .Func::code($item['sel_props_val']) . '","' .Func::code($item['count']) . '","' .(!empty($item['value']) ? Func::code($item['value']) : '' ). '","' .Func::code($item['sku_id']) . '","' .(!empty($item['user_desc']) ? Func::code($item['user_desc']) : '' ). '","' .Func::code($item['detail_url']) . '","' . $this->order_id . '","' .v($item['post_price']) . '","' .(!empty($item['post_type']) ? Func::code($item['post_type']) : ''). '","' .Func::code($item['img']) . '","' .Func::code($item['params_rus']) . '","' .Func::code($item['params_ch']) . '","' .Func::code($item['city']) . '","' .Func::code($item['state']) . '")');                
            if($query)
                $this->items[] = $item;
        }
        else
        {
            $_SESSION['current_order']['items'][] = $item;
            $this->items[] = $item;
        }
    }

    public function getOrder()
    {
        if($this->session==true)
        {
            if(!empty($_SESSION['current_order']))
                $this->order = $_SESSION['current_order'];
            else
                $this->order = array();

            return;
        }   
        if(!empty($this->order_id))
        {

            $result = $this->Mainclass->Db->get_("select * from `".$this->ot."` WHERE `order_id`='".$this->order_id."'");
            if($result)
            {
                //$this->order = mysql_fetch_object($result);
                $this->order = $result;
            }
        }
    }
    public function getPageLimit($posts)
    {
        $this->allResult = $posts;
        $total = intval(($posts - 1) / $this->itemFromPage) + 1;

        $page = intval($this->page); 
        if(empty($this->page) or $this->page < 0) $this->page = 1; 
          if($this->page > $total) $this->page = $total;

        $start = $this->page * $this->itemFromPage - $this->itemFromPage;
        return 'LIMIT '.$start.', '.$this->itemFromPage;
    }

    public function getOrdeItem()
    {

        if($this->session==true)
        {
            if(!empty($_SESSION['current_order']['items']))
                $this->items=$_SESSION['current_order']['items'];
            else $this->items = array();
            return;
        }
        else
        {

            $lResult = $this->Mainclass->Db->get_("SELECT `id` FROM `".$this->it."` WHERE `order_id`='".$this->order_id."'");

            $sql = $this->Mainclass->Db->get_("SELECT * FROM `".$this->it."` WHERE `order_id`='".$this->order_id."' ORDER BY `id` DESC ".$this->getPageLimit(count($lResult)),1);
            if($sql)
            {
                    $this->items[$sql['item_id']]=$sql;
            }

        }
    }

    public function updateOrder($conv = true)
    {
        if($conv)
            $this->conversion();

        if(!empty($this->order))
        {

            if($this->session==true)
            {
                    $_SESSION['current_order'] = $this->order;
                    $_SESSION['current_order']['items'] = $this->items;

            }

            $upd = array();
            foreach($this->order as $k=>$d)
                $upd[]="`".$k."`='".$d."'";

            $sql = $this->Mainclass->Db->insert_("UPDATE `".$this->ot."` SET ".implode(",",$upd)." WHERE `order_id`='".$this->order_id."'");

            //echo mysql_error();

        }
    }

    /*Пересчет стоимости веса и количества*/
    public function conversion()
    {
        if(!empty($this->items) and is_array($this->items))
        {

                $this->order['summ_0']=0;
                $this->order['weight']=0;
                $this->order['items_count']=0;

                foreach ($this->items as $item) {
                    $this->order['weight'] += (empty($item['value']) ? 0 : $item['value']) * $item['count'];
                    if($item['is_warehouse']!=3 and $item['back']!=1)
                    {
                        $this->order['summ_0'] += $item['price']*$item['count']+$item['post_price'];
                        $this->order['items_count'] += $item['count'];
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    private function generate_rand()
    {
        $temp = mt_rand(10000, 999999);
        $query = $this->Mainclass->Db->get_('SELECT `order_id` FROM `orders` WHERE `order_id`="'.$temp.'"',1);
        $queryCart = $this->Mainclass->Db->get_('SELECT `order_id` FROM `cart` WHERE `order_id`="'.$temp.'"',1);

        if(count($query)>0 or count($queryCart)>0)
            return $this->generate_rand();
        else
            return $temp;
    }

    public function getNewOrder()
    {

        $user = $_SESSION['user'];
        if ($user['user_type']==2)
            return;

        $this->order_id = $this->generate_rand();
        $this->order['order_id'] = $this->order_id;
        $this->order['order_date'] = date('Y-m-d [H:i:s]');
        $this->order['order_state'] = 10;
        $this->order['post'] = $user['post'];
        $this->order['post_deposit'] = $user['post_deposit'];
        $this->order['moderator_posent'] = $user['moderator_posent'];

        $this->order['mediator'] = $user['mediator'];
        $this->order['summ_0'] = 0;
        $this->order['summ_rate'] = 0;
        $this->order['summ_1'] = 0;
        $this->order['summ_all'] = 0;
        $this->order['summ_fact'] = 0;
        $this->order['user_login'] = $user['login'];
        $this->order['address_id'] = '';
        $this->order['pay_type'] = '';

        $result_db = $this->Mainclass->Db->get_("SELECT `user_login` FROM `mediators` ORDER BY rating DESC",1);
        if ($result_db!=false) {
            $this->order['mediator'] = $result_db['user_login'];
        }

        $sql = $this->Mainclass->Db->insert_("INSERT INTO `".$this->ot."` (`".implode("`,`",array_keys($this->order))."`) VALUES ('".implode("','",array_values($this->order))."')");

        echo mysql_error();
    }

    public function toTempCart($idArr)
    {
        if(empty($idArr) or !is_array($idArr) or $this->session==true)
        return false;

        $idStr = implode(",",$idArr);

        $this->Mainclass->Db->insert_("INSERT INTO `cart_tmp` (`user`,`num_iid`,`title`,`title_ch`,`nick`,`price`,`sel_props_val`,`count`,`value`,`sku_id`,`user_desc`,`detail_url`,`order_id`,`item_id`,`post_price`,`post_type`,`img`,`params_rus`,`params_ch`,`city`,`state`,            `ordered_time`)
                    SELECT `ord`.`user_login`,`it`.`num_iid`,`it`.`title`,`it`.`title_ch`,`it`.`nick`,`it`.`price`,`it`.`sel_props_val`,`it`.`count`,`it`.`value`,`it`.`sku_id`,`it`.`user_desc`,`it`.`detail_url`,`it`.`order_id`,`it`.`item_id`,`it`.`post_price`,`it`.`post_type`,`it`.`img`,`it`.`params_rus`,`it`.`params_ch`,`it`.`city`,`it`.`state`,`it`.`ordered_time`
                    FROM `cart_items` as `it`,`cart` as `ord`
                    WHERE  `ord`.`order_id`='".$this->order_id."' AND `it`.`order_id`=`ord`.`order_id` AND `it`.`item_id` NOT IN (".$idStr.")");

        $this->Mainclass->Db->delete_("DELETE FROM `cart_items` WHERE `cart_items`.`order_id`='".$this->order_id."' AND `cart_items`.`item_id` NOT IN (".$idStr.")");
        $this->updateOrder();

    }

    public function toItemsTable()
    {

        $order = $this->Mainclass->Db->get_("SELECT `user_login` FROM `cart` WHERE `order_id`=".$this->order_id);
        if(empty($order)) return false;

        $this->Mainclass->Db->update_("UPDATE `cart_tmp` SET `order_id`='".$this->order_id."' WHERE `user`='".$order['user_login']."'");

        $record = $this->Mainclass->Db->insert_("INSERT INTO `cart_items` (`num_iid`,`title`,`title_ch`,`nick`,`price`,`sel_props_val`,`count`,`value`,`sku_id`,`user_desc`,`detail_url`,`order_id`,`item_id`,`post_price`,`post_type`,`img`,`params_rus`,`params_ch`,`city`,`state`,`ordered_time`)
                    SELECT `num_iid`,`title`,`title_ch`,`nick`,`price`,`sel_props_val`,`count`,`value`,`sku_id`,`user_desc`,`detail_url`,`order_id`,`item_id`,`post_price`,`post_type`,`img`,`params_rus`,`params_ch`,`city`,`state`,`ordered_time`
                    FROM `cart_tmp`
                    WHERE  `user`='".$order['user_login']."'");

        $this->Mainclass->Db->delete_("DELETE FROM `cart_tmp` WHERE `user`='".$order['user_login']."'");

        $this->updateOrder();

        return $record;
    }

    public function deleteItemsFromArr($idArr)
    {

        if(is_array($_SESSION['user']))
        {
            foreach($idArr as $itd)
                unset($this->items[$itd]);

            $idStr = implode(",",$idArr);
            $this->Mainclass->Db->delete_("DELETE FROM `cart_items` WHERE `order_id`='".$this->order_id."' AND `item_id` IN (".$idStr.")");

            $this->order['items_count'] = count($this->items);
            $this->updateOrder();
        }   
        else
            foreach($_SESSION['current_order']['items'] as $k=>$d)
                if (in_array($d['item_id'], $idArr))
                    unset($_SESSION['current_order']['items'][$k]);

    }

    private function sessionItemToBase()
    {
        if($_SESSION['user']['user_type']>1)
            return false;
        if(!empty($this->order_id))
        {
            foreach($_SESSION['current_order']['items'] as $d)
            {
                $this->setItemCat($d);
            }
            unset($_SESSION['current_order']['items']);
        }

    }

    public function updateItemParam($id,$param)
    {
        if(!empty($this->items[$id]) and !empty($param) and is_array($param))
        {
            foreach($param as $k=>$d)
            {
                if(isset($this->items[$id][$k]))
                {

                    $this->items[$id][$k] = $d;
                    if(!in_array($id,$this->updateItemId))
                        $this->updateItemId[] = $id;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function updateItems()
    {

        if(!empty($this->items) and !empty($this->updateItemId))
        {
            foreach($this->updateItemId as $kid=>$itId)
            {
                if(!empty($this->items[$itId]))
                {
                    $upd = array();
                    foreach($this->items[$itId] as $k=>$d)
                    {
                        if($k!="id")
                            $upd[]="`".$k."`='".Func::code($d)."'";
                    }

                    //  print_r($upd);
                    $sql = $this->Mainclass->Db->update_("UPDATE `".$this->it."` SET ".implode(",",$upd)." WHERE `item_id`='".$itId."'");

                    echo mysql_error();
                    unset($upd);
                    unset($this->updateItemId[$kid]);
                }   
            }
        }   
    }
    /*
    Array ( 
        [checkbox] => 1  //Двойная коробка 
        [checkbox2] => 0 //Полная обмотка коробки скотчем 
        [checkbox3] => 1 //Пластиковые стяжки 
        [checkbox5] => 1 //Обмотка каждого товара пузырчатой плёнкой 
        [checkbox4] => 5000 //Страховка посылки 
    ) 
    */
    public function parseUslugi($usl = array())
    {
        $tempUsl = !empty($usl) ? $usl : $this->order['uslugi'];
        $tUslArr = array();

        if(!empty($tempUsl))
        {
            $uslArr = explode("|",$tempUsl);

            $tUslArr['summ'] = 0;
            foreach($uslArr as $d)
            {
                list($key,$dat) = explode(":",$d);
                switch($key)
                {
                    case "checkbox": $sum = 320; break;
                    case "checkbox2": $sum = 320; break;
                    case "checkbox3": $sum = 150; break;
                    case "checkbox4": $sum = (int)$dat; break;
                    case "checkbox5": $sum = $this->countPl($dat,20); break;
                    case "checkbox6": $sum = 120; break;
                    case "checkbox7": $sum = $this->countPl($dat,100); break;
                }
                if(!empty($dat))
                {
                    $tUslArr[$key] = $sum;
                    $tUslArr['summ']+=$sum;
                }
            }

        }
        return $tUslArr;
    }

    public function countPl($data,$stoim)
    {

        $datAyy = explode(";",$data);
        $dataResult = $this->Mainclass->Db->get_("SELECT SUM(`count`) as `cou` FROM `".$this->it."` WHERE ".($this->it=='items' ? "`back`=0 and " : "" )." `item_id` IN (".implode(",",$datAyy).")",1);
        $sum_pl = 0;

            if($dataResult)
            {
                $sum_pl=$dataResult['cou']*$stoim;
            }

        return $sum_pl;
    }

    public function setType($type)
    {
        if(!empty($type))
        {
            switch($type)
            {
                case "order":
                {
                    $this->ot="orders";
                    $this->it="items";
                    break;
                }
                case "cart":
                {
                    $this->ot="cart";
                    $this->it="cart_items";
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function cartToOrder()
    {

        $this->Mainclass->Db->insert_("INSERT INTO `items` (`num_iid`,`title`,`title_ch`,`nick`,`price`,`sel_props_val`,`count`,`value`,`sku_id`,`user_desc`,`detail_url`,`order_id`,`item_id`,`post_price`,`post_type`,`img`,`params_rus`,`params_ch`,`city`,`state`,`ordered_time`)
                        SELECT `num_iid`,`title`,`title_ch`,`nick`,`price`,`sel_props_val`,`count`,`value`,`sku_id`,`user_desc`,`detail_url`,`order_id`,`item_id`,`post_price`,`post_type`,`img`,`params_rus`,`params_ch`,`city`,`state`,`ordered_time`
                        FROM `cart_items`
                        WHERE  `order_id`='".$this->order_id."'");

        $this->Mainclass->Db->insert_("INSERT INTO `orders` (`order_id`,`to_order`,`parent_order`,`order_state`,`order_date`,`puti_date`,`user_login`,`post_deposit`,`moderator_posent`,`mediator`,`post`,`state`,`sum_cur`,`summ_0`,`summ_1`,`summ_rate`,`summ_all`,`summ_fact`,`weight`,`items_count`,`post_price`,`post_price_rate`,`mediator_price`,`address_id`,`pay_type`,`order_comments`,`type_fact`,`reorder`,`uslugi`)
                        SELECT `order_id`,`to_order`,`parent_order`,`order_state`,`order_date`,`puti_date`,`user_login`,`post_deposit`,`moderator_posent`,`mediator`,`post`,`state`,`sum_cur`,`summ_0`,`summ_1`,`summ_rate`,`summ_all`,`summ_fact`,`weight`,`items_count`,`post_price`,`post_price_rate`,`mediator_price`,`address_id`,`pay_type`,`order_comments`,`type_fact`,`reorder`,`uslugi`
                        FROM `cart`
                        WHERE  `order_id`='".$this->order_id."'");      
        $this->Mainclass->Db->delete_("DELETE FROM `cart` WHERE `order_id` = '".$this->order_id."'");
        $this->Mainclass->Db->delete_("DELETE FROM `cart_items` WHERE `order_id` = '".$this->order_id."'");
        echo mysql_error(); 
        $this->setType("order");        
    }

    public function getOrderStatus()
    {

        if(!empty($this->order['order_id']))
        {

            if(empty($this->items))
            {
                $result = $this->Mainclass->Db->get_('SELECT `is_warehouse` as `status`,COUNT(*) as `count` FROM `items` WHERE `order_id`='.$this->order['order_id'].' GROUP BY `is_warehouse`',1);
                $status = $result;

                $dopl = $this->Mainclass->Db->get_('SELECT COUNT(*) as `count` FROM `items` WHERE `order_id`='.$this->order['order_id'].' and `back`=0 and `new_price`>0 and `is_pay`=0 GROUP BY `is_warehouse`');
            }
            else
            {
                $status_temp = array('0'=>0,'1'=>0,'2'=>0,'3'=>0);
                $status = array();

                $dopl = array('count'=>0);

                foreach($this->items as $d)
                {
                    $status_temp[$d['is_warehouse']]+=1;
                    if($d['back']!=1 and $d['new_price']>0 and $d['is_pay']==0)
                        $dopl['count']+=1;

                }
                foreach($status_temp as $k=>$d)
                {
                    $status[] = array(
                        'status'=>$k,
                        'count'=>$d,
                    );
                }
            }

            if(!empty($status))
            {
                $data = array(
                    '0'=>0,
                    '1'=>0,
                    '2'=>0,
                    '3'=>0,
                    'is_pay3'=>(int)$this->order['is_pay3'],
                    'is_pay1'=>(int)$this->order['is_pay1'],
                    'post_price_fact'=>(int)$this->order['post_price_fact'],
                    'doplata'=>(int)$dopl['count'],
                    'post_code'=>!empty($this->order['post_code']) ? 1 : 0,

                );

                foreach($status as $k=>$d)
                {
                    $data[$d['status']] = (int)$d['count'];
                }

                return $this->parseStatus($data);   
            }
        }

    }

    private function parseStatus($data)
    {
        /*if($this->debug)
        {
            echo "<pre>".print_r($data,1)."</pre>";
        }*/

        $secssus = 0;
        $status = array(

            '1'=> array(
                '0'=>'>',
                '1'=>'x',
                '2'=>'x',
                '3'=>'x',
                'is_pay1'=>'1',
                'is_pay3'=>'0',
                'post_price_fact'=>'0',
                'doplata'=>'0',
                'post_code'=>'0'
            ),//В обработке
            '2'=> array(
                '0'=>'0',
                '1'=>'>',
                '2'=>'x',
                '3'=>'x',
                'is_pay1'=>'1',
                'is_pay3'=>'0',
                'post_price_fact'=>'0',
                'doplata'=>'0',
                'post_code'=>'0'
            ),//На склад
            '3'=> array(
                '0'=>'0',
                '1'=>'0',
                '2'=>'>',
                '3'=>'x',
                'is_pay1'=>'1',
                'is_pay3'=>'x',
                'post_price_fact'=>'>|0',
                'doplata'=>'0',
                'post_code'=>'0'
            ),//Нужно взвешать
            '-1'=> array(
                '0'=>'0',
                '1'=>'0',
                '2'=>'0',
                '3'=>'>',
                'is_pay1'=>'1',
                'is_pay3'=>'x',
                'post_price_fact'=>'x',
                'doplata'=>'x',
                'post_code'=>'0'
            ),//Нет в наличии
            '4'=> array(
                '0'=>'x',
                '1'=>'x',
                '2'=>'x',
                '3'=>'x',
                'is_pay1'=>'1',
                'is_pay3'=>'x',
                'post_price_fact'=>'x',
                'doplata'=>'x',
                'post_code'=>'1'
            ),
            '5'=> array(
                '0'=>'0',
                '1'=>'0',
                '2'=>'x',
                '3'=>'x',
                'is_pay1'=>'1',
                'is_pay3'=>'0',
                'post_price_fact'=>'>',
                'doplata'=>'0',
                'post_code'=>'0'
            ),
            '6'=> array(
                '0'=>'x',
                '1'=>'x',
                '2'=>'x',
                '3'=>'x',
                'is_pay1'=>'1',
                'is_pay3'=>'0', 
                'post_price_fact'=>'x',
                'doplata'=>'>',
                'post_code'=>'0'
            ), //Доплата за товар

        );

        foreach($status as $k=>$d)
        {
            $statusS = true;

            foreach($d as $sk=>$sd)
            {

                switch($sd)
                {
                    case '>|0':
                    {
                        $ts1 = true;
                        $ts2 = true;
                        if(empty($data[$sk]) or $data[$sk]<0) $ts1=false;
                        if(!empty($data[$sk])) $ts2=false;
                        if(empty($ts1) and empty($ts2)) $statusS=false;
                        break;
                    }
                    case '0':
                    {
                        if(!empty($data[$sk])) $statusS=false;
                        break;
                    }
                    case '1':
                    {
                        if(empty($data[$sk])) $statusS=false;
                        break;
                    }

                    case '>':
                    {

                        if(empty($data[$sk]) or $data[$sk]<0) $statusS=false;
                        break;
                    }

                }
            }

            /*if($this->debug)
            {
                echo $k." ".($statusS ? 1 : 0)."<bR>";
            }*/

            if($statusS == true)
            {
                $secssus = $k;
                //break;
            }
        }
        return $secssus;
    }

    public function getChild($state = 60)
    {
        if(empty($this->order['order_id'])) return false;

        $sql = $this->Mainclass->Db->get_("SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE `to_order`=".$this->order['order_id']." AND `order_state`='".$state."'",1);

        $this->child = $sql;

    }

    public function getChildItem()
    {
        $order_id = array();
        if(!empty($this->child))
        {
            foreach($this->child as $d)
                    $order_id[] = $d['order_id'];

            $sql = $this->Mainclass->Db->get_('SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE `order_id` IN ('.implode(',',$order_id).')  ORDER BY nick',1);

            foreach($sql as $k=>$d)
            {
                $this->childItems[$sql['order_id']][] = $d;
                $this->childItemsCount++;
            }
        }
        else return false;
    }

    public function detectStatus()
    {
        $new_status = true;
        $this->dStatus = $this->order['admin_status'];

        if(!empty($this->child))
        {
            foreach($this->child as $childData)
            {
                if(!$new_status) continue;
                if($this->dStatus!=4 AND $this->dStatus!=5 AND $this->dStatus!=2)
                switch($childData['admin_status'])
                {
                    case "0":
                    case "1":
                    case "2":
                    case "3":
                    case "5":
                    case "6":
                    {
                        $this->dStatus=$childData['admin_status'];
                        $new_status = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Проблема в mainclass.php, скиньте 46 строку оттуда.

Comment: нет проблема не в mainclass.php, а в его использовании в другом классе, отдебажить не получаеться потому что фатальная ошибка такого вида, я просто не понимаю что она означает.

Comment: >Fatal error: Trying to get string form class Mainclass in  // точно form или from???

Ошибку сами писали или скопипастили? Код в студию!

Строку 46, а лучше весь класс выложите куда-нибудь.

Comment: а вообще строка 46 выглядит так,
function __toString()
{
 trigger_error('Trying to get string form class    '.get_class($this),E_USER_ERROR);
 return '';
}

Comment: Класс в котором ошибка выложил в вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо, что откликнулись, ошибку нашел, это стандартная ошибка класса была, говорит что я пытаюсь использовать класс как строку)